# How to restore GRUB when Windows 7 MBR lost it?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows, grubrescue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

My dual boot desktop was running only Windows 7 until it crashed on a windows update.

Couldn't get it started again even after all the usual things that might fix it, so I installed Ubuntu 12.04, which has worked very well.

unfortunately Carbonite doesn't run on Linux yet, and so I called Microsoft support to see if we could be Windows 7 up and running.

Their attempts to get Windows 7 running resulted in writing a new MBR for windows, which failed and also somehow caused the loss of ability to boot into Ubuntu also.

How can I get back to Ubuntu?

I don't want to lose my settings in Ubuntu.

Comment: There is additional info required, Trent. Do you know which partition Ubuntu is installed to? If so, you should be able to boot a live cd/usb to mount and chroot the Ubuntu partition. Then you can reinstall GRUB to the MBR.

Comment: You dont want to lose any of your settings, boot using a live ubuntu cd and just download bootinfo script from this http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/ link and pastebin the results here. So that we can help you.

Comment: @mattdavis is right. Paste the output of the bootinfoscript as i have given you the link in previous comment. So that we can reinstall grub.